# Using pointer with array

Tags: arrays, c

I am learning pointers in C programming.
A piece of code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int ary[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int *p = ary + 3;
        printf("%d\n", p[-2]);
    }
```

`ary` is the array and how is the `*p` pointing to the `ary+3` and output coming is `2.` How is the pointer handling the array values? I looked into https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/ but I did not found how pointer is influencing array there?

Comment: The pointer arithmetic works in a similar way to array indexing. The array decays to a pointer, so `ary + 3` has the same value as `&ary[3]`.

Comment: i tried to see the different result by changing index. p[0] gives '4'  and p[1],p[2] gives '0' how is this seen?

Comment: `p[1]` and `p[2]` are indexing beyond the last element of the original array, which is undefined behaviour and the values found are irrelevant.

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/) has some really bad code posted.  `sizeof(p) = %lu` is undefined behavior and flat out ***wrong*** on 64-bit Windows systems where `size_t` is 64 bits and `long` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to understand.

We know `arr`is an array but the `arr` reference will always point to an address of a starting element of the array.

So, for above example.
`arr` is point to address of `arr[0]` (value 1).
`arr + 3` will point to the `arr[3]` (value 4).

That means pointer `p` is point to `arr[3]`.
Now, `p[-2]` will move the pointer 2 address back and will point to `arr[1]` (value 2).

Hence the output 2 !

Answer (score 2):

The array syntax `p[-2]` is equivalent to, `*(p - 2)`, since `p` is pointing to `ary + 3` which is the fourth element in your array, decrementing the pointer by 2, will print 2.

`p[0]` will print the value `p` is pointing to, since `*(p + 0)`, any other positive index will result in accessing the array out of bounds, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`<sup>1</sup>, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes! - more on that below) from that address and dereference the result.  `ary[0]` is equivalent to the expression `*(ary + 0)`, which is equivalent to `*ary`, `ary[1]` is equivalent to `*(ary + 1)`, etc.

The expression `p[-2]` is equivalent to `*(p - 2)`; since `p == ary + 3`, then `p - 2 == ary + 3 - 2 == ary + 1`, which is the address of the second element of `ary`.  Thus, `p[-2] == ary[1] == 2`.

Pointer arithmetic is based on the size of the pointed-to type - if `p` contains the address of an object of type `T`, then `p + 1` yields the address of the next *object* of that type.  For example, given

```
char  *cp = (char *)  0x1000;
short *sp = (short *) 0x1000;
long  *lp = (long *)  0x1000;
```

then we have the following:

```
Address    char            short          long
-------    +---+           +---+          +---+         
0x1000     |   | cp        |   | sp       |   | lp
           +---+           + - +          + - +
0x1001     |   | cp + 1    |   |          |   |
           +---+           +---+          + - +
0x1002     |   | cp + 2    |   | sp + 1   |   |
           +---+           + - +          + - +
0x1003     |   | cp + 3    |   |          |   |
           +---+           +---+          +---+
0x1004     |   | cp + 4    |   | sp + 2   |   | lp + 1
           +---+           + - +          + - +
            ...             ...            ...
```

---

1. Arrays are not pointers - however, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.